# Fseek doesn't sets the file position of the stream in C

Tags: c, fseek

i make this simple C program whose purpose is to count the characters that are in a text file which is given through the second command line argument.
 The problem i face is that fseek shows not responds with a result to have an infinite loop (while(!feof(fp)))  in function "Counter".By replacing the fseek with a fgetc the programm works fine.My my question is what is going wrong with the fseek.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Counter (FILE * fp);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int cntr;
   FILE * fpc;
   fpc = fopen(argv[1],"r");
   cntr = Counter(fpc);
   fclose(fpc);
   printf("%i\n",cntr);
}

int Counter (FILE * fp)
{
    int cntr = 0;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        cntr++;
        fseek(fp,1,1);
    }
    return cntr;
}
```

Comment: Use constant `SEEK_CUR` instead of 1, it makes the code clearer.

Comment: I have used it with the same result

Comment: See [Why is `while(!feof(file)) always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Of course, because `SEEK_CUR` is defined as `1` :) What does `ftell(fp)` tell you in the middle of the `while` loop?

Comment: Consider using `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)` combined with `ftell()`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `fgetc()` if you feel obligated to count bytes one by one.

Comment: Yes, `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); cntr=ftell();` will give you what you're expecting.

Comment: I am geting the same result with this fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); cntr=ftell();

Comment: "Why is `while(!feof(file)) always wrong?"  was very usefull thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed and well defined behaviour to seek beyond the end of a file.

That's why `fseek()` does not set the end-of-file indicator, it even more unsets it on success.

From the [C Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2):

> 5 After determining the new position, a successful call to the fseek function [...] clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream, and then establishes the new position.

Comment: Good catch! I have seen code where you can write a byte, `fseek` 1 GB further and write another byte, leading to the file system seeing a 1 GB file fitting on a 256 MB disk.